# How do I convert a list of maps to a set?

Tags: terraform

I have a `for_each`

```
  for_each = toset([
    "A@Dcom",
    "B@D.com",
  ])
```

but I want it taken from a CSV file with unique `Email` column values

```
Email,Name
A@Dcom,A
B@D.com,A
```

The `csvdecode()` function will convert the CSV into

```
[
  {
    "Email" = "A@Dcom",
    "Name" = "A",
  },
  {
    "Email" = "B@Dcom",
    "Name" = "B",
  }
]
```

Which function should I use to just get a set (or tuple because I can just use `toset()`) of e-mail addresses?

Answer (score 0):

```
for_each = toset(
  [for e in csvdecode(file("data/MyFile.csv")) : e.Email ]
)
```